# Redirecting to route with parameters if response is success using Ajax and Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I created a form that register an order requested by the user logged in when he hits the submit button on the plan he chooses. It's working fine.
But I want to redirect to checkout route for paying that order after the order is registered on database. I'm using ajax to validate inputs in client side.

**My problem is that I don't know how to redirect it to a route with the plan parameter after the response is successful.**

This is the route I want to redirect to:

```
{{ route('payments', ['plan' => $plan->identifier]) }}
```

Here's my validation on client side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-plan").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        var app_name = $("input[name='app_name']").val();
        var domain = $("input[name='domain']").val();
        var new_domain = $("input[name='new_domain']").val();
        var alojamento = document.querySelector('input[name="alojamento"]:checked').value;
        var criar_email = document.querySelector('input[name="criar_email"]:checked').value;
        var facebook = $("input[name='facebook']").val();
        var instagram = $("input[name='instagram']").val();
        var linkedin = $("input[name='linkedin']").val();
        var categoria = document.querySelector('input[name="categoria"]:checked').value;
        var contact = document.querySelector('input[name="contact"]:checked').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: config.routes.zone,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { _token: _token, categoria: categoria, contact: contact, app_name: app_name, domain: domain, new_domain: new_domain, alojamento: alojamento, criar_email: criar_email, facebook: facebook, instagram: instagram, linkedin: linkedin },
            success: function(data) {

                if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {

              // It's supposed to be something here to redirect to the route

                } else {
                    printErrorMsg(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function printErrorMsg(msg) {
        $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
        $(".print-error-msg").css('display', 'block');
        $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it inside success

```
window.location.href = "{{ url('/xxxxx') }}'";
```

Comment: Only worked with "{{ route('/xxxxx') }}"; but thank you! I didn't think it would be that easy